# Build To Order Products in WooCommerce -- overriding product combinations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, composite

I am trying to set up a site with very complex "build to order" products. I am using WooCommerce but I realize that it might not be best solution, however, I am not a programmer so I'm trying to work with a pre-existing application. For reference, here is the original site that I'm redesigning: http://www.cabinetstogo.com/ic280Collectionfrm_multiple.asp?prodno=TOFFEE-NS*WC -- click on the tabs to see the detail.

I have explored all the Woo Extensions I can find such as Product Add Ons, Product Bundles, Grouped Products and Composite Products. Currently I am using **Product Bundles** with **Composite Products** here: 
http://www.cabinetstogo.company/product/westminster-glazed-toffee-base-cabinets/ -- the layout is a bit messy but that isn't my issue, the issue is that while you can pick and choose individual products you can't select individual quantity.

With **Grouped Products**: http://www.cabinetstogo.company/product/grouped-test/ the layout is perfect but I can't add a Grouped Product to a Composite Product.

Ideally what I need to do is:

1. Create Product Bundles of simple products that have to be sold together
2. Organized these Product Bundles into Product Groups -- **PROBLEM: Bundled products can't be added to Group Products**
3. Add these Product Groups into a Composite Product for a master group of products like Base Cabinets  -- **PROBLEM: Grouped products can't be added to Composite Products**

I have tried Product Add Ons two but the issue with that is there is no way to set individual SKUs for the Add Ons.

Setting them as Variable Products is another idea but you can't select more than one variation at a time. I have also considered the Gravity Forms Add On but that seems to just be for additional product details not the mix and match features.

I know there is no easy solution but any pointing in the right direction would help as I can think of all different ways to go about I don't know where to start.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Force Sells](http://www.woothemes.com/products/force-sells/) WooCommerce extension? It doesn't solve the problem of "can't add grouped products to the cart" issue, but you can force certain products into the cart when a specific one is added. Might be worth looking into.

Comment: yea i've looked into all of the options. there is no one perfect solution.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean in 1,2 and 3. I'm having a hard time visualizing. I went to your old website and it looks like a "grouped" product with per/unit pricing. If nothing out of the box works, you might need some custom development work done.

Comment: @CreativEliza - what did you end up doing?  Did you resolve this issue?  I'm deep into some WooCommerce solutions right now, and am wondering.

Comment: I basically created a series of grouped products because that allowed me to set the quantity individually. I hid the individual projects that made up the group products so you only saw the grouped ones. then I created pages that linked to the different groupings and overrode the woocommerce pages for shop and category so that the only woocommerce pages were the grouped ones.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for an off the shelf plugin solution for a VERY complicated problem. You're going to need a programmer for this. A good basic plan could be:

```
FEATURE: Do custom business logic when a particular product is purchased.
   When a customer adds something to the cart
   Then do some custom business logic, like add "bundled" products to the cart
```

Here are some useful snippets functions:

```
Do something on cart add:
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function custom_add_to_cart( $cart_item_key, $product_id ) {
    if( 123 == $product_id ) { ....

OOP:
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array($this, 'doSomething') );

Create a product:
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'no');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'yes');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', $regularPrice);
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', "123" );
```